# Can we get tracking for different types of reviewing actions?

Tags: feature-request, review, profile-page

Similar to the total number of upvotes/downvotes listed on the profile page, can we get totals for the different review actions? This would not have to be visible on the profile, but maybe visible on the `/review` page, under "Stats".

I know you can see all the `/review` actions at site/user?tab=activity&sort=reviews:

[image]

But you can also see all the question votes too, *and* you get a nice little table of the upvotes, downvotes, by question/answer.

[image]

**Can we track how we respond to `/review` actions so each user can see how they are actioning reviews as a whole?**